# Given an arbitrary sequence {$x_n$} in $\Bbb{R}$, find a test function $f$ with $f^{(n)}(0)=x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Given an arbitrary sequence {$x_n$} in $\Bbb{R}$, can I find a test function having the $n$-derivative equal to $x_n$ at $0$?

Comment: If you take the $k^{th}$ derivative of an $n^{th}$ degree polynomial, what is the constant term? What can you multiply the constant term by to get $x_k$?

Comment: You are right!So I need to divide n!And to satisfy the condition of test function I only need to define f is zero if x is out of [-1,1].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Taking the $n^{th}$ derivative of an infinite polynomials gives:

$
f^{(n)}(z) = n!(a_n) +  ((n+1)!/1!)(a_{n+1})z + ((n+2)!/2!)(an_{n+2})z^2 + ...$

$f^{(n)}(z) = n!(a_n) + O{(z)}
$

So in general we need $a_n = x_n/n!$

Hence the function is $f(z) = x_0 + x_1z + (x_2/2)z^2 + ... + (x_n/n!)z^n + ...$

Comment: I think it is right.Thank you

Comment: You're welcome! If you find this answer satisfactory please consider accepting it by clicking the ✓ sign right next to it.

Comment: If $x_n = (n!)^2$ then your series is divergent for all $x \neq 0$, so it doesn't exist.